# ¿"Favela" es una palabra de la lengua española?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, hispanoamérica, portugués

En la canción *Machika* (J. Balvin con Jeon y Anitta), la cantora brasileña tiene los siguientes versos:

> Caliente hasta en la nevera
>   En la cima sin escalera
>   La sensación de la **favela**
>   Salió a romper fronteras

Como el español no es su lengua materna, y no sería su primera vez [introduciendo palabras portuguesas en sus músicas](https://play.google.com/music/preview/Trz6jgrygaidngjc3remtljdmyu?lyrics=1&utm_source=google&utm_medium=search&utm_campaign=lyrics&pcampaignid=kp-songlyrics&u=0#), yo supuse que esa palabra no sería parte de la lengua española. Sin embargo, conversando con una amiga peruana, ella me ha dicho que *favela* es una expresión conocida y regularmente usada en el resto de la América del Sur.

He buscado en algunos diccionarios, pero [todos son claros](http://dle.rae.es/?id=HgkfhfT) en decir que es una [palabra prestada del portugués](http://diccionarios.elmundo.es/diccionarios/cgi/diccionario/lee_diccionario.html?busca=favela&diccionario=1&submit=Buscar%20). Hasta [la entrada en Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favela) se refiere a ella como un fenómeno exclusivamente brasileño. Cuando el mismo fenómeno es observado en países hispanoparlantes, la palabra *chabola* es la única empleada.

Mi duda es: ¿hay algún país de lengua española donde la palabra *favela* sea un término genérico y no un fenómeno predominantemente brasileño?

Comment: Pienso que la sola definición del DLE hace que sea un extranjerismo porque no fuimos nosotros en español los que empezamos a llamar las chabolas de Brasil así sino que fueron ellos y nosotros lo adoptamos. Que en el DLE no este en cursiva es simplemente una omisión como tantas que tiene el DLE. A propósito la palabra chabola es la primera vez que la escucho y en Colombia no se usa.

Comment: Está en portugués pero es fácil de leer. En el párrafo 3 está el origen de la palabra favela https://matracacultural.wordpress.com/2011/04/17/voce-sabe-o-que-esta-falando/

Comment: @walen sí, hasta le pregunté si se refería a las chabolas de Brasil, pero ella dijo que usaban la misma palabra, aunque _chabola_ sea más común. Quizás sea un término que esté se quedando más popular con el tiempo, pero no parece haber sido aceptado aún. He encontrado muchas noticias en español a respecto de las favelas, pero todas fueran sobre favelas brasileñas.

Comment: La palabra tampoco está en el Diccionario de Americanismos de la RAE. [(Enlace)](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=favela)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A mí la verdad es que no me extrañaría que ya se estuviese usando **favela** como sinónimo de **chabola**, especialmente en países cercanos a Brasil.
Se empieza por conocer lo que son las favelas en Brasil (introducción), se sigue por describir (por ejemplo) "las chabolas de Perú, similares a las favelas de Brasil" (comparación), se continúa por "las chabolas, conocidas como «las favelas de Perú»" (asimilación), y se acaba por decir "las favelas", sin más (sustitución).

Te iba a decir que en España no se usa, pero sorpresa, sorpresa:

- Introducción: [¿Es seguro hacer turismo en las favelas de Río?](http://www.lavanguardia.com/ocio/viajes/20180207/44563196062/seguridad-visitar-favelas-rio-de-janeiro-brasil.html)
- Comparación: [El mayor asentamiento ilegal de España y similar, en menor medida, a las favelas de Brasil](https://dialnet.unirioja.es/servlet/articulo?codigo=3085977).
- Asimilación: [Las 'favelas' de Ibiza](http://www.elmundo.es/baleares/2016/07/19/578d3879268e3e64138b4597.html).
- Sustitución: [Unión Fenosa quita la luz a las favelas de la Cañada Real](https://elpais.com/diario/1995/03/21/madrid/795788659_850215.html); [Favelas, Cañada Real y la propiedad](https://lalibertadylaley.wordpress.com/2008/04/23/favelas-canada-real-y-la-propiedad/).

Como ves, **el uso de *favela* para referirse tanto a poblados de chabolas como a las propias chabolas, está vigente desde hace varios años en España**. Me sorprendería que no fuese así también en otros países. Sólo falta que el DLE se actualice.

Comment: Completamente de acuerdo @walen aunque faltó la conclusión lógica. Favela **si** es una palabra de la lengua española que aunque por ahora en el DLE solo hace referencia a Brasil, por el uso popular en muchos lugares ya ha sido incorporada al español con el mismo significado. +1

Comment: Recuérdame que nomine esta respuesta para la votación de las mejores del primer trimestre de este año. Me ha encantado. Breve, concisa y rotunda. +1

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta fantástica. El último enlace emplea _favela_ como un sinónimo natural de _chabola_, sin ninguna mención anterior al Brasil, y lo haces en una publicación impresa de 1995. Me ha impresionado que haya construido tal respuesta mismo después de sugerir que ella se hubiera confundido.

Comment: Sí, fui yo que lo había sugerido. Aún así, estoy impresionado.